# Как с помощью js в атрибут href указать относительный путь

Tags: javascript, html

```
const galleryCartA = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery_cart-a');

galleryCartA.forEach(function (el) {
    let ahref = el.querySelector('img').getAttribute("src");
    el.querySelector('img').setAttribute("alt", el.querySelector('img').getAttribute("src"));
    el.setAttribute("href", el.querySelector('img').getAttribute("alt"));
    alert(el.href);
})
```

Есть библиотека для работы которой мне необходимо перенести значение из дочернего элемента **img** значение атрибута **src** в **href** родительской ссылки с классом **gallery_cart-a** и этот путь обязательно должен быть относительным, но когда я присваиваю относительный путь атрибуту **href** родительского элемента путь становиться абсолютным. Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать путь в **href** относительным

Answer (score 0):

При выполнении вашего скрипта ссылке присваивается относительный путь, но когда вы вызываете `alert` с `el.href`, то показывается полный путь. Если вызвать `alert` с `el.getAttribute("href")`, то будет показан относительный путь.
Пример:

```js
const galleryCartA = document.querySelector('.gallery_cart-a'); //Так как в примере 1 ссылка, то forEach убран и ваш код выполняется с этой единственной ссылкой

let ahref = galleryCartA.querySelector('img').getAttribute("src");

galleryCartA.querySelector('img').setAttribute("alt", galleryCartA.querySelector('img').getAttribute("src"));

galleryCartA.setAttribute("href", galleryCartA.querySelector('img').getAttribute("alt"));

//Обработчики кликов по кнопкам
document.querySelector('.withoutGetAttr').addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert(galleryCartA.href)
})
document.querySelector('.withGetAttr').addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert(galleryCartA.getAttribute("href"))
})
```

```html
<p>У тега img src="../1.png"</p>
<a class="gallery_cart-a" href="#"><img src="../1.png"></a>

<button class="withoutGetAttr">Вызвать alert(element.href)</button>
<button class="withGetAttr">Вызвать alert(element.getAttribute("href")</button>
```

Comment: да, я это заметил, но в href ссылки в любом случае вставляется абсолютный путь

Comment: Если вы пишите, что у вас всё происходит так, как показано в примере, то вы присваиваете href тоже самое, что находится в src. Вот итог выполнения вашего кода: https://sun9-15.userapi.com/impg/nj6-PFSzTq-tQ7_N7vwmBgi6ikg-8CihQShRTQ/II1H8wOckbQ.jpg?size=305x39&quality=96&sign=dba847d8b084eb8cd89ad1dbce5773b4&type=album. Покажите скриншотом как у вас выглядит html после выполнения кода. Может вы не хотите, чтобы имелась возможность перехода по ссылке, но относительный путь был в ней записан?

Comment: Я пересмотрев, то что у меня получается на выходе понял, что ошибка была не из-за этого, спасибо, если б не ты я б не обратил на то внимание

Comment: Я часов пять парился с этой проблемой, а ошибка была в порядке подключаемых скриптов.